# error in formula. trying to understand meaning

Tags: java

i would like to understand where i am going wrong. I receive an error on the output? My understanding is: "-" stands for left justified. 20 for 20 characters in length field and %n stands for next line.  so i am unsure what i have done incorrectly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class forTesting {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Name;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name:");
    Name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("%-20 %n", "Name:" , Name);   
  }
}
```

Comment: ...and you forgot to mention what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your objective is, I think it's to print "name:" and on the next line the name, but you did forget the "s", in addition, why not use the System.out.println method? It's simpler and easier to use.

```
String Name;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter name:");
Name = input.nextLine();
// use: System.out.println("name:");
//      System.out.println(Name);
System.out.printf("%-20s %n", "Name:" , Name);
```

Comment: this is just one input.  if there are many is this method still the simplest?

Comment: Yea even though it takes 2 line it would be the simplest, if this does answer your question please do mark this as answered.

Comment: This code does not print `Name`.  It requires another `%s`.

Comment: @saka1029 yes, sorry i forgot to include that, thank you